# I am getting an error "Uncaught Reference Error: jsf is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JSF2.2 with RichFaces4.5. I have an xhtml page with a custom defined jsf tag for pdf pop up. But when I click on the pdf link in the page, I am getting the error:

> Uncaught Reference Error: jsf is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

in the browser JavaScript console.

I saw few questions which have been already posted related to this issue and the answers provided were to include head or body tags in the xhtml page. I tried those but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: To get a paragraph break in a Stack Overflow post, simply press Enter twice - that forms the _Markdown_ syntax for a new paragraph. If you use that, your posts will be significantly easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was jsf.js was not initializing in the xhtml page.I added the following line (without double quotes surrounding the greater than/less than symbol) in my xhtml inside h:head tag and its working fine.

**"<"h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/">"**